# Player facing at the wrong direction when stopping

Tags: lua, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I am using tic-80, and when the player stops, the `xvelocity` becomes `1.942...-16`.

I'm new to this, so I can't really see what the problem is.

Here's my [code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Fasf6GxDzhdKIRgVhLIa8NKdiEjLCxII).

Comment: I can't either, with what you've shared with us so far, and probably nobody else can either. Does all of the code you're shown us pertain to this problem? If not, post the part that does here. Next, none of your variables clearly show that they pertain to xvelocity. I can guess that `p.vx` and `p.x` probably have something to do with it, but I'm not interested in wasting your and my time by guessing wrong. Next, I'm not quite sure what `1.942...-16` means. So, please remove irrelevant code from your example, and explain what your relevant code is doing. That way, someone can probably help you.

Comment: You are using floating point numbers like `.1` and `.01`. So, it is absolutely normal that you are getting an approximation instead of exact result. `1.942...-16` is very close to zero.

Comment: As @BobRodes said, it is impossible to understand what you are actually asking. Please post any relevant code (or even better, a [MCVE]) in your question (do not post a link, as these can become invalid -- you can edit your question and add the code to it) and tell us what you want your code to do and what it actually does. If you are surprised that you get a value that is only *close* to 0, instead of *exactly* 0, then you should read up on the problems with floating point.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Oh, `1.942...-16` means `1.942E-16`. I'm unfamiliar with that notation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, I know that. I meant that I was unfamiliar with the notation `1.942...-16` to mean the same thing. I think that the OP might have invented it at this point. It isn't a lua thing as far as I've been able to determine.

Comment: @BobRodes: It looks like standard ellipsis: an omission of characters replaced by “…”. There is some question as to whether some software performed the elision (as might occur in a GUI debugger when the string representing a value does not fit in the window for it—the debugger’s formatter replaces the middle characters) and the OP copied it  or the OP performed the elision. (If the OP copied it, they likely did it manually. A copy operation on such a window usually provides the entire text.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's possible, but I'm skeptical that an ellipsis was used to replace an `E`. I can't imagine any software application replacing a single letter with one, and it seems unlikely that the OP would. However, perhaps there is a much longer string in there that the OP thought was irrelevant. In any case, this is a fine example of the sort of things one finds in death march problem statements.

Comment: @BobRodes: The ellipsis I posit would have been done by software ignorant of the meaning of text in a cell. It would be general rendering software that simply takes whatever is desired to be displayed in a cell, sees it will not fit, and removes stuff in the middle to make it fit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I've never seen any software that removes characters from the middle of a string in that situation as opposed to truncating the string. But there's a lot of software I haven't seen, so maybe so.

Comment: @BobRodes: I have seen such ellipsis in the middle. Windows does it too, e.g. for long filenames.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis So it does, and I've even seen it too, now that you mention it. :) But I still can't imagine that there's any place where an ellipsis would substitute for a single character.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the player stops"? Do you mean when the player is currently not pressing either of the arrow keys?